# Return a String from a Two-Dimensional Array in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have a two-dimensional array:

```
var beatlesComposers = [
  ['George', 22 ],
  ['John', 71 ],
  ['Paul', 71 ],
  ['Ringo', 2 ]
];
```

The first element is the name of the composer, and the second represents the number of songs written by that composer.

How do I return the name of the composer with the last largest number of songs written (in this instance 'Paul' with 71)?

Comment: If you post the code you have tried, we can help you determine why it's not working the way you want.

Comment: "*in this instance 'Paul' with 71*" What about John? He also has 71.

Comment: This looks like homework.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `reduce` to look at the second element of each array and find the highest.  Used `>=` instead of `>` in the comparison makes the latest element win in case of ties.

```
var beatlesComposers = [['George', 22 ],['John', 71 ],['Paul', 71 ],['Ringo', 2 ]];

var mostWritten = beatlesComposers.reduce(function(prev, curr){
  return curr[1] >= prev[1] ? curr : prev;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could always just do a basic Array sort:

```
var beatlesComposers = [['George', 22 ],['John', 71 ],['Paul', 71 ],['Ringo', 2 ]];

beatlesComposers.sort(function(artist1,artist2){
  return artist2[1]-artist1[1]
});

beatlesComposers[0]; //This is now ['John', 71]
```

Now the first element in "beatlesComposers" will be the artist with the  largest number of songs written.